# Solve differential equation involving $y$ through $^{(5)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to self-study in advance but I'm having a hard time.

> Solve the linear differential equation: $$\bigl(y^{(5)}–12y^{(4)}+52y^{(3)}–112y''+192y'–256\bigr)y = 0$$

Comment: is $$D5y=y'''''(x)$$?

Comment: I got (D-4)^3(D^2 +4) , what's next then?

Comment: I got now the equation: Y=(C1 + C2x + C3x^2) e^4x) +.. What about my D^2+4? How can I put that in my equation?

Comment: I can't  What is the complex root of D^2+4 ? Is it 2i? But what is the complex conjugate of that?

Comment: This is not a linear dif. eq. because it is not of the form $y’ + f(x)\,y=g(x)$.